# Should I implement dealloc in my app delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uikit

Should I implement dealloc in my app delegate and release my ivars there? As I understand it, when an app gets terminated, all the memory associated with it gets freed automatically. So basically, there's no need to release any ivars yourself at termination.

I've found this question here already: [Does it make any sense to release ivars in appdelegate's dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456828/does-it-make-any-sence-to-release-ivars-in-appdelegates-dealloc)

One of the answers says that objects might have clean up code in dealloc, so you might want to release ivars yourself at termination. But when I put an NSLog in the dealloc of my app delegate, it's never called. My assumption is there's no use at all for it so I don't even have to implement it, am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be necessary in future iOS releases. For the sake of forward compatibility, and since Apple seems to recommend it I would release those ivars.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you don't need to release your ivars in dealloc (The example templates that come with the SDK do have a -dealloc though). The OS will reclaim any memory associated with you app. If anything, it will just add a small amount of overhead. Also, as far as I know, there isn't any guarantee by the environment that the -dealloc in your app delegate will ever get called, so it may never even execute.